# Absolute URL Cookieless

Tags: asp.net, redirect, cookieless

Is there some method in asp.net for getting an absolute url with cookieless session?

UPDATE: I need create other new URL. It is not requested URL.

I´m using Response.ApplyAppPathModifier for getting relative URL with cookie session.

Thx in advance,

Comment: Can you give a bit more background. How does the cookie affect the URL?

Comment: What is a “URL with cookieless session”?

Comment: @Gumbo: a url with cookieless session in ASP.NET is what you end up with when you set in the web.config <sessionState cookiess="true" />. Please check my answer for more information.

Comment: @XIII: So the session ID is just put in the HTTP URL instead of the HTTP header.

Comment: @Gumbo: the SessionID indeed becomes a part of the url. You don't see it that frequently being used however.

Comment: @Gumbo there is some proxies (for example, WAP proxies) that they remove http headers

Answer (score 3):

I tried Request.RawUrl and Request.Url (and its properties in the Immediate window).
None did show the extra attribute the setting (web.config):

```
<sesionState cookieless="true" />
```

makes in the url.

Example

> http://localhost:2677/WebSite1/(S(3abhbgwjg33aqrt3uat2kh4d))/cookielesssessiondetection.aspx

However if you're after that part, `3abhbgwjg33aqrt3uat2kh4d`, you can get it via:

```
Session.SessionID
```

Update after the updated question:

I put in my test application a Hyperlink control on the page. In code behind, Page_Load, I added:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("About.aspx");
```

When I run that page then the url to About.aspx gets set with the cookieless session part included.

When I check the source of the rendered html in my browser I see this:

```
<a id="HyperLink1" href="/WebSite1/(S(3tzgdnmhwxmxqer10d11auuq))/About.aspx">HyperLink</a>
```

Comment: UPDATE: I need create other new URL. It is not requested URL.

Comment: Yes, this is a relative URL, but i need Absolute URL, i´m using string.format for getting domain. But i hope to exist one especific function. Thx for you help.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific function out of the box. However you can make a completely new Uri instance and pass in the pieces with some string formatting on the Request.Uri property.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Request.Url.ToString(). It should work for you.
If you needed was the url of another page on your site then you can proceed like this...

String url = new Uri(Context.Request.Url,  ResolveUrl("~/ABC.aspx")).ToString )

We also have something like Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

I hope One of the above should work for you.

Comment: I don´t know why. But ResolveUrl not work with cookieless URL.