# strange text in localhost url

Tags: asp.net

I am using development server, not IIS (I think) and my url strings are coming out differently when I try to browse to the page I'm working on.

The usual way they looked;
  localhost:44044/Account/Register.aspx

Now they look like this;
  localhost:44044/(S(rzoxv2lrex3xsh1o1lsfdnpf))/Account/Register.aspx

Does anyone have a clue where that section after localhost comes from? And I'm wondering if that's why I'm getting a specified cast error now when I try to run the page (it was working earlier)

Comment: This kind of behavior also get generated when we use cookieless="UseUri" in form authentication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a [cookieless session identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) in ASP.Net. This is caused by how the application is configured in web.config.

Check for: `<sessionState cookieless="true" />` at the web.config or machine.config level.

As far as your casting error goes, we would need to see some code. If your configuration has changed (as the cookieless session implies), then your application could be failing due to another configuration change.

See also: [Cookieless sessions in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372965/cookieless-sessions-in-asp-net)

Comment: Not sure how or why it changed. I did go thru the asp.net web configuration to use MySQL as my Membership Provider. I h=just tried to set cookieless to False and got a warning from VS2012 that False is invalid? Do I just remove that line from the config file?

Comment: You can probably just remove it...the default is false (lowercase "F").

Comment: Im going to post the other problem separately as it has nothing to do with this obviously.

Answer (score 1):

That is the Session Identifier, if you don't allow the Session Identifier to be stored in a cookie.

If, in your web.config, in the `sessionstate` node, you have `cookieless="true"`, then the identifier gets put into the url so that it is still be available to the server to retrieve the user's session.

See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178582%28v=vs.100%29)