# Does ASP.NET Session state work without cookies?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-state

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> By default, the SessionID value is stored in a non-expiring session
>   cookie in the browser.

If I am trying to use Session State (I'm not using Cookieless Session IDs) and a users browser does not accept cookies, will Session State work?

Comment: I'm confused.. You say you refuse to use cookieless sessions and then complain that sessions (with cookies, because you won't accept cookieless sessions) won't work without cookies?  No, cookie based sessions won't work if the browser won't accept cookies.  That shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this it is supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

The downside is that the session ID is placed in every URL used by the application:

```
http://yourserver/folder/(session ID here)/default.aspx
```

See this SO answer for additional details: [Absolute URL Cookieless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180697/absolute-url-cookieless/3180804#3180804)

Comment: For a very standard asp.net site this will work as long as you don't use cookies for anything else important but expect to rework any javascript which generates links dynamically and any non standard redirecting.