# Cookieless Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, form-authentication

I have a requriement to implement Authentication in a ASP.NET website (public website, not intranet). But the client do not want to enable cookie, even they do not want URL rewrite. Is there a way to achieve Form Authentication satisfying above conditions? Or Is there any other kind of Authetication suitable for this scenario?

Comment: Is there a problem using cookie-less session?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719374/461810

Comment: @Dusan - the OP wanted no URL rewrites, in which that cookieless option performs a lot of URL rewrites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are using something like AngularJS you can keep the token in javascript and pass it back and forth.

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

However if you need to stay purely in the realm of ASP.NET and you won't be using any MVVM frontend framework, then cookies or URL rewriting are the only 2 options I am aware of. Well, only 2 plausible options I am aware of. They are some other ways I know but they violate many security principles.